# How do I extend class derived from StatelessService in Service Fabric ASP.NET 5 - based service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

Is there a way to subscribe to an actor event from ASP.NET 5 - based service? I saw similar feature in [service-fabric-dotnet-data-streaming-websockets](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-dotnet-data-streaming-websockets) sample, but the sample uses OWIN-based web service and it has `PublicGateway` class derived from `StatelessService` where one can hook to the service `Task RunAsync` override. I haven't found any `StatelessService`-derived type in the ASP.NET 5 - based project code. Seems like it's auto-generated, if to look into the project ServiceManifest.XML?

The goal I'm trying to achieve is the same with the sample - I want to subscribe to events from actor service to publish them through SignalR hub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference you're seeing is that the OWIN (Katana, to be precise) sample is a Service Fabric Reliable Service - a service written on the Service Fabric API - that uses Katana to open an HTTP listener. The ASP.NET 5 (now called ASP.NET Core 1) project you're seeing is what we call a "Guest Host" which is a separate EXE hosted by Service Fabric but doesn't implement any of the Service Fabric APIs. The reason it's done this way currently is because the current ASP.NET Core 1 hosting model makes it difficult to open a web server programmatically like we do with Katana.

However, this is changing. The upcoming RC2 of ASP.NET Core 1 will let you easily start a web server programmatically, similar to the way we do it with Katana, so you can write a service on the Service Fabric API and open an ASP.NET Core 1 server from the service. Here is an example using the RC2 build: https://github.com/weidazhao/Hosting

That said, you don't necessarily need to be inside a Reliable Service to hook into actor events. Any code running in the cluster can do it by pulling in the Reliable Actors NuGet package (Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors) and using the ActorProxy API. You can do this in a Guest Host service, you just won't have RunAsync as an entry point to do it in.

Comment: Well, it makes sense about Guest Host.

Comment: But could you elaborate on subscribing to event from the ASP.NET 5 project code? Because I tried to do so in the server Startup code and wasn't able to receive events from my Actor. And I even more curious about subscribing in e.g. controller code. 
Eventually when event is raised I suspect Fabric should find subscriber partitions, send the event to a listener port and there should be always running process which listens to the port in the partition process. Is this even possible in the Guest Host case?

Comment: It should be possible as long as the Guest Host is running in the same cluster. Follow this guide for subscribing to actor events. Note that the guide doesn't assume the subscriber itself is a service of any kind. It just needs to be some class that inherits the IActorEvents interface that has the event contract. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-actors-events/