# How do I add an extra service endpoint to an "ASP.NET 5" type service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-service-fabric

From this ([How do I extend class derived from StatelessService in Service Fabric ASP.NET 5 - based service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476040/how-do-i-extend-class-derived-from-statelessservice-in-service-fabric-asp-net-5)) answer I understand that ASP.NET 5 services are actually "Guest Hosts" that don't have access to the Service Fabric platform's API. Does this mean that I cannot add another service endpoint that uses a `ServiceRemotingListener`? If I can: how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah that's true with the RC release of ASP.NET 5 that's out right now. It runs as a Guest EXE which means you don't have access to the Service Fabric APIs directly.

With upcoming releases of ASP.NET Core 1 we'll be able to use it as a communication listener inside a Service Fabric service (just like the Service Remoting Listener).

Comment: Thanks. I take it as no, then. In the meantime I've found this: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-webapi/ that solves my problem